# Javascript string.match with specific prefix and text after

Tags: javascript, regex

Maybe somebody can help me with getting part data from string.

```
let input1: string = "any string before specialPrefix: ['content1', 'content2'] and any other text after";  
let input2: string = "any string before specialPrefix:['content1', 'content2'] and any other text after";  
let input3: string = "any string before specialPrefix: 'content1', 'content2' and any other text after";
```

expected

output1, output2: array with two values,
'content1' and 'content2'.
output3: empty array

Comment: Try this `/\[.*\]/` regex

Comment: it will fail on 'any data [some text]' - empty result is expected. As I understand, my question look very stupid. Unfortunately I cannot create this kind of regex.

Comment: Actually, your question isn't clear, what is specific prefix here?

Comment: It is predefined text. In sample it's equal to 'specialPrefix:'

Comment: For the above, is it `specialPrefix` ?

Comment: It's 'specialPrefix:' with optional space after

Comment: Regex is evil, dont't ever use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `/specialPrefix:\s*(\[.*?\])/`

```js
let inputs = ["any string before specialPrefix: ['content1', 'content2'] and any other text after","any string before specialPrefix:['content1', 'content2'] and any other text after","any string before specialPrefix: 'content1', 'content2' and any other text after"];  
var result = inputs.map(str => (/specialPrefix:\s*(\[.*?\])/.exec(str) || [])[1]);
console.log(result);
```